# In which cases does the nonlinear conjugate gradient method take more than $n$ steps?

Tags: convex-optimization, conjugate-gradient

I have programmed a couple of Matlab implementations of nonlinear Conjugate Gradient methods (Fletcher Reeves and Polak Ribeire). However, I am concerned with how many steps it's taking to optimise the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + 5x^4 + 10y^2$, roughly 100. I have read that the bound for convergence is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space my function lives in.

Are there properties of this function's Hessian/Gradient that mean that this bound doesn't apply in this case? If so why? Are there any simple functions to test my implementation with, that have an expected convergence rate?

**Edit 1:**
I should mention that the tolerance is set quite low, $10^{-12}$, is this probably the issue? Why should it be so if it is?

Comment: Would you mind adding the complete bibliographic information?

Comment: I'm reading Nocedal and Wright's Optimization textbook.

Answer (score 4):

The nonlinear conjugate gradient method will converge for a quadratic function in $N$ steps at most. You do not have a quadratic function, and have no guarantees on convergence. It can be helpful to reset your search direction every $N$ steps or to use a better method (i.e., Newton's method). A simple function that you could use to test would be a quadratic function, one with the form: $$f = \lvert\lvert(b - Ax)\rvert\rvert^2$$ for scalar functions, this is a parabola (for positive a and b), and should be very easy to check as you have a closed-form expression for the solution. For vector functions, $A$ is a matrix, $b$ and $x$ are vectors and you solve for $x$ to minimize the function $f(x)$. When you move beyond quadratic functions, you can look at the Rosenbrock problem which is numerically tricky but has a known solution and is a good validation case for basic algorithms and codes.

EDIT: I edited for clarity. You also have a fairly obvious typo in your formula. Is one of the $x^2$ terms supposed to be a $y^2$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ll try out a simple quadratic function and see what happens. I’ve also added a edit for the typo!